# SwingWorker get not finishing

Tags: java, swing, swingworker

I have been using quite some SwingWorkers recently, and had some issues so I tried to create an SCSSE, but that apparently doesn't want to work

```
static SwingWorker worker;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    worker = new SwingWorker<Object, Object>() {
        protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
            return "Hello";
        }
        protected void done() {
            System.out.println("I'm done!");
        };
    };
    System.out.println("working");
    try {
        System.out.println("result: " + worker.get());
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("working finished");
}
```

when this is executed, it prints "working" and then the script continues to run indefinitely...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never start the `SwingWorker`, so the `worker.get()` method is blocking while it waits for the worker to complete.

You can verify this by adding:

```
System.out.println("waiting for result");
System.out.println("result: " + worker.get());
```

If you want the `SwingWorker` to execute then you need to invoke:

```
worker.execute()
```

after you create the `SwingWorker`.

Comment: oh wow that was a stupid mistake. I thought it would be invoked automatically if it hasn't been already.